# Example of a double-free vulnerability in C

Tags: c

I hope this is the correct forum to ask for the question that I have:
We are currently discussing double-free vulnerabilities in our software security class, which is why I know the code given below is suppossed to be an example of how a double-free can be exploited. Now, I am trying to understand this example and I hope that somebody here can help me with this.

The first thing done in this code is a definition of a struct auth. We use this struct by defining a pointer to such a struct: 
`struct auth *auth;`

Ok. I think a vulnerability can only be where `malloc` or `free` have been used. But what could possibly be exploited in this specific code? I don't see it. I remember from class that the problem with applying `free` to the same pointer twice is, that now the chunk's forward- and backward pointer are pointing to this very same chunk that they themselves are stored in. That's about where my knowledge ends.

I would be so glad to find someone here, who might help!

```
struct auth {
  char name[32];
  int auth;
};

struct auth *auth;
char *service;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char line[128];

  while(1) {
      printf("[ auth = %p, service = %p ]\n", auth, service);

      if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) break;

      if(strncmp(line, "auth ", 5) == 0) {
          auth = malloc(sizeof(struct auth));
          memset(auth, 0, sizeof(struct auth));
          if(strlen(line + 5) < 31) {
              strcpy(auth->name, line + 5);
          }
      }
      if(strncmp(line, "reset", 5) == 0) {
          free(auth);
      }
      if(strncmp(line, "service ", 7) == 0) {
          service = strdup(line + 8);
      }
      if(strncmp(line, "login", 5) == 0) {
          if(auth->auth) {
              printf("you have logged in already!\n");
          } else {
              printf("please enter your password\n");
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Small Edit: With the answers given to the post, I came up with a solution. Simply type the following lines:

```
auth me
reset
service AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
login
```

The input written after `service` is 36 characters. Now, what is happenning in this program? `auth me` allocates 36 Bytes of memory on the heap. `reset` frees this memory, however it is not set to NULL. Now `service` again allocates 36 Bytes of memory on the heap. It is very likely that the same memory that was allocated before by `auth` will be allocated. In this memory we can still find the name `me`. This is written in the last 4 Bytes of this memory area.

Comment: It would be nice if you could paste the code as text instead of as a screenshot :) Just paste it in then highlight it and press the code format button (this puts 4 spaces in front of each line to make sure it is monospaced).

Comment: @Captain Man: Ok, sure. I can only open the program on our Campus, actually. So I will have to do it tmrw. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program repeatedly prompts the user for an operation to perform, taking as input a string that is supposed to start with one of "auth ", "reset", "service ", or "login" (it will not handle any other string very gracefully). Assuming that the input string is acceptable, the program will perform some operation and them prompt again. Notably, this means you can enter the same command twice in a row.

- "auth " will cause the allocation of a `struct auth` (one of three things with that name, either the developer is terrible or the code is deliberately confusing) from the heap, and assign its address to the `auth` pointer variable. Calling this more than once will leak memory unless the `struct auth` pointed to by `auth` is freed in between calls.
- "reset" will free the memory pointed to by the `auth` pointer variable. This is safe to do if `auth` points to `NULL` or if `auth` points to a valid, heap-allocated memory buffer (such as the `struct auth` allocated by the "auth " operation). However, calling `free` on a pointer does not reset it to `NULL`, so **if you do a "auth " followed by *two* "reset"s (without another "auth " in between), then you will get a double-free**. What happens at that point is undefined by the C spec, so it depends on your particular implementations of `malloc` and `free`, but in practice is usually exploitable for memory corruption and thus potentially for arbitrary code execution.
- "service " is entertainingly bugged (it only checks for the first 7 characters, not the space, so you can potentially end up calling `strdup` on memory that has no null bytes before hitting an unmapped page, in which case the program will crash). It also never frees the memory that `strdup` allocates, so using "service" more than once will result in a memory leak. It is probably not relevant here, though.
- "login" will attempt to dereference the pointer variable `auth` and check the value of the pointed-to `struct auth`'s field that is also called `auth` and is an integer. This will fail with a segfault/access violation if the pointer variable `auth` is null or points to an invalid (unmapped) address (or rather, if any of the 33rd-36th bytes beyond that address are not mapped). This is also probably not relevant here.

So, now you know how to trigger a call a double-free in this code. Actually exploiting that is left as an exercise for the student. Bring a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

That code have some issues that you should correct.

1. If the user types "reset" the first time, you have a free of something that you didn't allocate, also the pointer should be initialize to null to help (auth = NULL)
2. If the user types "login" the first time, your code will generate a SIGSEV on auth->auth, you didn't allocated auth properly.
3. on the call malloc you should verify that the return value is not null.

There are more issues on the code, but are more related to bad programing practices than a security related from my point of view

Comment: thx so much, camp0!  Now, can you explain the 2. point a little bit more detailed for me? I am new to this security topic. How is this allocation wrong? If I type in "login" for the first time, the condition         `if(auth->auth)` will be checked. I am actually not really sure what `auth->auth` does. I think it means: `auth` points to a struct, and now I am accessing the element `auth` of this struct.

Comment: @user503842 One of the truly bad coding practices in this sample are that there are three things called `auth`. #1 is a struct type, #2 is a field of type `int` within that struct type, and #3 is a global variable of type "pointer-to-`struct auth`" (pointer-to-#1). The line `if (auth->auth)` takes #3 (the pointer variable), dereferences it (implicitly yielding a #1 `struct auth` value), and determines whether that value's #2 "auth" field (bytes 32-35 of the struct, interpreted as an `int`) are 0 or not. However, this whole process will crash if the variable #3 is `NULL` or otherwise invalid.